# Gson date deserializer not working

Tags: android, json, json-deserialization

I have a json text:

> [{...,lastUpdateDate=Sep 1, 2016 6:00:00 AM,operators=[{callSetupCharge=0, displayName=AUS VFONE; AUS VODA; 505 03,...}],visible=true}]

I'm trying to convert the text into object, but for some reason deserializer is not working. I've debugged, and first line in method deserialize() is equal to "Sep"

```
  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
       .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateDeserializer()).create();
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<CountryDto>>(){}.getType();
        ArrayList<CountryDto> countryList = gson.fromJson(text, listType);


public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement element, Type arg1, JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        String date = element.getAsString();

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy H:mm:ss a");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

        try {
            return formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to parse Date due to:"+ e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The field lastUpdateDate is causing problem:

> Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:
>   Unterminated object at line 1 column 136 path $[0].lastUpdateDate

Comment: It doesn't look like a JSON

Comment: i'm only giving part of the text. It is json I assure you

Comment: Can you post all of it in JSON format, not toString-ish dump? MalformedJsonException doesn't usually happen to well formed JSONs...

Comment: can you update the date format to MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa and check?
also if this doesn't work set the date to string to make sure the issue is with date not the return string json format

Comment: I can see *lots of* missing double quotes. I think that you don't know what JSON string format really is

Comment: BTW your date format looks fine and should work, you have another problem with jour JSON and we need more of it to work it out.

Comment: @Mr Quattro I'm downloading json response and saving it in .json file in build stage. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Why are you reluctant in posting the full JSON or at least a character-by-character-part of it

Comment: @MrQuattro full json is huge, stackoverflow doesn't allow more than n characters. I've edited with more json, please have a look

Comment: @Nazerke Is this `JSON`? A `JSON` should be in format `"key" : "value"`. The format you have given is `key = value`,

Comment: Please, validate your JSON using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com). What you pasted isn't valid JSON, there are missing double quotes and other weird constructs.

Comment: @MrQuattro That's what I'm getting through gradle's httpbuilder. I'm working out why is it so. Will let you know. Thanks guys, I wouldn't have thought about quotes

Comment: Thank you guys, the problem was due to lack of quotations. I've replaced groovy's buggy http-builder package with smth else, and now it's returning normally. It's all working. Do you want to add it as an answer or should I answer my own question?